# Using python to fill fields on a website, perform some actions on the returned results?

Tags: python, web-scraping

A little background - I'm a student, broke and I'd like to travel on the cheapest trains to some nice destinations. Hence this idea was born.

I am comfortable with Python, I have worked with it for its data analysis and machine learning libraries.

Now, I want to be able to use a train ticket booking website to fill the Departure, Arrival, Date, Time, Number of Passengers fields for all destinations offered and find the cheapest train to take. I want to be able to do some actions of the results returned like, for example, choosing the 2nd earliest train while leaving or the 2nd last train while departing. I don't want to automate the booking part, I will do that part myself.

In a nutshell, I just want to automate the part where I input multiple destinations and waste 2 hours of my day trying to find cheap trains.

I have no idea where to start and I looked into some blogs, most of them offered solutions with JavaScript and I have zero knowledge of it. Can I not achieve the above goal with just Python? What libraries will I need for this?

Comment: You'll probably want to look into Selenium or PlayWright for Python. You'll want to get familiar with CSS-selectors and using your browser's developer tools, like Chome dev tools, to inspect the DOM, log network traffic, etc.

Comment: This activity is called web scraping. Perhaps googling that will give you some guidance. You can usually find an api on the site you want to get data from, send them your input (departure, arrival, ...) as json and get back a json response. Then you can manipulate the json data in Python with ease. The difficulty of this will greatly vary based on the site you're trying to scrape, some won't get you json. You can try to see if you find a scraping guide for the specific site you want online.

Comment: Some libraries you can look into are BeautifulSoup, requests, and Selenium, they are very useful webscraping libraries for Python. Selenium likely fits your use case scenario best, as it can be used to interact with the website (type destinations, click links, navigate around the webpage, etc.), as well as extracting information from the website itself such as prices.